# accessing the key of a dictionary using only one element from its value

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I have two dictionaries, one, a class to function dictionary:

```
{'A': ['__init__', 'message'],
 'Head': ['__init__', 'talk'],
 'Human': ['__init__', 'createHead']}
```

another, a class to subclass dictionary:

```
{'Human': ['A', 'Head']}
```

Here, classes 'A' and 'Head' are inside class 'Human'.

I derive this class from the first library using the functions,(assume i know all the functions in a particular class).

Is it possible to get Human' just with 'A'? (i.e., I just know one element in the value list of second dictionary)

Comment: It is possible but you have to do it manually.

Comment: You mean you want to iterate over all the key/value pairs in the second dictionary, and find all the keys for which 'A' is in the value list?

Comment: Why are you dealing with these dictionaries to begin with? What is your goal?

Comment: I want to create instances for every class and call these functions in another file. So I am iterating over every class separately, Hence I need to get 'Human' when I parse 'A'.

Comment: @JJ_29 it still isn't clear to me what your goal is? Are you creating the dictionaries above by hand? There is almost certainly a better way to achieve your goal...

Comment: No, I am generating these dictionaries by parsing a python script into my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can traverse the dictionary, and return any keys that contain the value you're searching for using list comprehension:

```
class_to_func = {'A': ['__init__', 'message'],
    'Head': ['__init__', 'talk'],
    'Human': ['__init__', 'createHead']}
class_to_subclass = {'Human': ['A', 'Head']}
matching_classes = [key for key,value in class_to_subclass.items() if 'A' in value]
print(matching_classes)
```